# How do I find the limit of this function as $x\to1^-$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^3}}.$$
I tried l'Hôpitals, however it seems like no matter how many times you differentiate, it will still be in the indeterminate form. Is there another way to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Factor out $\sqrt{1-x}$. Canceling that common factor gives us $$\sqrt{\frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{(1-x)(x^2 + x + 1)}} = \sqrt{\dfrac {1+x}{x^2 + x + 1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $1-x^2 = (1-x)(1+x), 1-x^3 = (1-x)(1+x+x^2)$. You can simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^3}=\frac{1+x}{1+x+x^2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Use $1-x^2 = (1-x)(1+x)$ and $1-x^3 = (1-x)(1+x+x^2)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L>0$ then $\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt L$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Factorize both the radicands in numerator and denominator, respectively as differences of squares and cubes.